# How do I control the timer using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am trying to create a `minutes:second` timer by requesting the user to type how long they want in minutes into the textbox which is `textbox2` but when I tried to do `get.ElementbyID.value` for the variable mins,it does not work and gave error`(NULL error`) as I try global variable which also does not work.

I required the user to be able to type into the textbox in minutes and when pressing the start button will start the time the user requested.

```js
var mins = 1;
var secs = mins * 60;
var currentSeconds = 0;
var currentMinutes = 0;

function start2() {
  start();
}

function start() {
  setTimeout(Decrement, 1000)
}

function Decrement() {
  currentMinutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  currentSeconds = secs % 60;
  if (currentSeconds <= 9) currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds;
  secs--;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds; //Set the element id you need the time put into.
  if (secs !== -1) {
    setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
  }
  if (secs == -1) {
    alert("hi");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox2" value="0"></input>
<br/>
<button onclick="start2();">Start Timer</button>
<br/>

<p id="timer"></p>
```

Comment: What is the specific line of code that does not work?  To get the value from the `<input>` tag you have, you would use `var time = +document.getElementById("textbox2").value;`.

Comment: did you really try `get.ElementbyID.value`? If yes, this might be the cause of your problem

Comment: When using `var mins = document.getElementById("textbox2").value;`,it gives me NULL error.

Comment: Please show us the exact code you were trying in the actual context you were using it.  `var mins = document.getElementById("textbox2").value;` will work fine if used in the proper context.   Keep in mind that it gives you a string, not a number so if you want it as a number, you have to convert it to a number.  ALWAYS show us the code you're using that doesn't work.  In this case, you strangely showed us only the part of the code that works, not the part that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem was you were trying to set the `mins` variable on page load. Instead, load the value in your `start` function.

You also need to calculate your seconds after determining the minutes.

```js
var mins = 1;
var secs = mins * 60;
var currentSeconds = 0;
var currentMinutes = 0;

function start2() {
  start();
}

function start() {
  mins = document.getElementById('textbox2').value;
  // set a default of 1 minute if it is less than one or not a number..
  mins = isNaN(mins) || mins < 1 ? 1 : mins;
  
  // calculate seconds down here, as well.
  secs = mins * 60;
  setTimeout(Decrement, 1000);
}

function Decrement() {
  currentMinutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  currentSeconds = secs % 60;
  if (currentSeconds <= 9) currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds;
  secs--;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds; //Set the element id you need the time put into.
  if (secs !== -1) {
    setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
  }
  if (secs == -1) {
    alert("hi");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox2" value="0"></input>
<br/>
<button onclick="start2();">Start Timer</button>
<br/>

<p id="timer"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var secs = 0;

function start(s) {
    secs = s;
    schedule();
}

function schedule() {
  setTimeout(Decrement, 1000)
}

function Decrement() {
  var currentMinutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  var currentSeconds = secs % 60;
  if (currentSeconds <= 9) currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;
  if (secs-- > 0 )
    schedule()
  else
    alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox2" value="0"></input>
<br/>
<button onclick="start( parseInt( document.getElementById('textbox2').value ) );">Start Timer</button>
<br/>

<p id="timer"></p>
```